# Basic app generation failing using jhipster: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addQmark' of undefined"

Tags: jhipster

Very basic application generation failing with error mention in title. I have upgrading Node to latest version 8.11.3, npm to 6.1.0 and installed latest yarn and  yo but still getting the same error.

### Attaching complete console log for application generation:

- ? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic
  application (recommended for simple projects)
- ? What is the base name of your application? automate
- ? What is your default Java package name? com.automate
- ? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and
  scale your application? No
- ? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT
  authentication (stateless, with a token)
- ? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL,
  MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
- ? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
- ? Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL
- ? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? No - Warning, when
  using an SQL database, this will disable the Hiber nate 2nd level
  cache!
- ? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend?
  Maven
- ? Which other technologies would you like to use?
- ? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular 6
- ? Would you like to enable *SASS* support using the LibSass
  stylesheet preprocessor? No
- ? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
- ? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to
  use?
- ? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster
  Marketplace? No

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addQmark' of undefined
    at Compiler. (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\nanomatch\lib\compilers.js:92:16)
    at Compiler.visit (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js:129:15)
    at Compiler.mapVisit (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js:143:12)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js:168:10)
    at Snapdragon.compile (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\snapdragon\index.js:156:32)
    at C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:786:23
    at memoize (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:859:13)
    at Function.micromatch.compile (C:\Users\dellPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:783:10)

Comment: Hi @Mayank,

I have also encountered the same error today after I have updated yarn. I get the below error when I try to run my tests.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addQmark' of undefined
    at Compiler.<anonymous>  

I'll let you know if i find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Mayank please report this as an issue to jhipster github community as it looks like a bug.